# While loop to break when pattern is found in all files?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, for-loop, while-loop

The below code searches for a set of patterns (contained in the $snps variable) within multiple files ($file variable for files ending in snp_search.txt) and outputs a long list of whether or not each snp is in each file.

The purpose is to find several SNPs that are in **all** of the files.

Is there a way to embed the below code in a while loop so that the it keeps running until it finds a SNP that is in all of the files and breaks when it does? Otherwise I have to check the log file manually.

```
for snp in $snplist; do
   for file in *snp_search.txt; do

     if grep -wq "$snp" $file; then
       echo "${snp} was found in $file" >> ${date}_snp_search.log; else
       echo "${snp} was NOT found in $file" >> ${date}_snp_search.log
     fi
   done
done
```

Comment: please update the question with a sample list of `SNPs` and a few lines from a `*.txt` file (lines that match and don't match the sample `SNP` values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` to search all the files. If the file names don't contain newlines, you can just count the number of matching files directly:

```
#! /bin/bash
files=(*snp_search.txt)
count_files=${#files[@]}
for snp in $snplist ; do
    count=$(grep -wl "$snp" *snp_search.txt | wc -l)
    if ((count == count_files)) ; then
        break
    fi
done
```

For file names containing newlines, you can output the first matching line for each $snp without the file name and count the lines:

```
count=$(grep -m1 -hw "$snp" *snp_search.txt | wc -l)
```

Comment: Hello choroba, Thank you so much for the response!! If I want your code to print the SNP that was found then would it work if I placed 

echo "The SNP $snp was found in all files" >>out.log

below the "fi"?

Comment: @SpencerK: Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- multiple SNPs may exist in a single line of an input file
- will print a list of **all** SNPs that exist in **all** files (OP has mentioned contradicting statements: `find several SNPs that are in all of the files` vs `break when one SNP is found in all files`)

Sample inputs (will update if OP updates question with sample data):

```
$ cat snp.dat
ABC
DEF
XYZZ

$ cat 1.snp.search.txt

ABCD-XABC
someABC_stuff
ABC-
de-ABC-
de-ABC
DEFG
zDEFG
.DEF-xyz
abc-DEF
abc-DEF-ABC-xyz

$ cat 2.snp.search.txt
ABC
```

One `GNU awk` idea that requires a single pass through each input file:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { snps[$1]=0; next }                        # load 1st file into array; initialize counter (of files containing this snp) to 0

FNR==1  { filecount++                               # 1st line of 2nd-nth files: increment counter of number of filds
          delete to_find                            # delete our to_find[] array
          for (snp in snps)                         # make a copy of our master snps[] array ...
               to_find[snp]                         # storing copy in to_find[] array
        }

        { for (snp in to_find) {                    # loop through list of snps 
              if ($0 ~ "\\y" snp "\\y") {           # if current line contains a "word" match on the current snp ...
                 snps[snp]++                        # increment our snp counter (ie, number of files containing this snp)
                 delete to_find[snp]                # no longer need to search current file for this particular snp
#                break                              # if line can only contain 1 snp then uncomment this line
              }
          }

          for (snp in to_find)                      # if we still have an snp to find then ...
              next                                  # skip to next line else ...
          nextfile                                  # skip to next file
        }

END     { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
          for (snp in snps)
              if (snps[snp] == filecount)
                 printf "The SNP %s was found in all files\n", snp
        }
' snp.dat *.snp.search.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- `GNU awk` is required for the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` option to sort the `snps[]` array indices; if `GNU awk` is not available, or ordering of output messages is not important, then this command can be removed from the code
- since we only process each input file once we will print **all** SNPs that show up in **all** files (ie, we won't know if a SNP exists in all files until we've processed the last file so might as well print all SNPs that exist in all fiels)
- should be faster than processes that require multiple scans of each input file (especially for larger files and/or a large number of SNPs)

This generates:

```
The SNP ABC was found in all files
```